# How to assign url to anchor tag based on absolute or relative url, href always gets updated with routerLink is this happening by default?

Tags: angular

I'm assigning values to href and routerLink attributes for anchor tag based on relative or absolute URL. When I do so it's getting rendered with href value when the URL is relative as well.

Html code which i used to render a tag and i'm assigning true or false to isAbsolute after checking the url is absolute or relative .

```
<a *ngIf="isAbsolute" [href]="linkUrl" [target]="target" >{{ LinkVal }}</a>
<a *ngIf="!isAbsolute" [routerLink]="linkUrl" [target]="target">{{ LinkVal }}
</a>
```

Result which rendered in browser with both href and routerlink

```
<a ng-reflect-target="_blank" ng-reflect-router-link="/abcd/abc" target="_blank" href="/abcd/abc" class="ng-star-inserted">contact us</a>
```

I expect output to have only routerlink or href in the  tag or by default href value will gets assigned whenever routerLink has been updated .Need help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I conditionally use either \[href\] or \[routerLink\] on an anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449202/how-can-i-conditionally-use-either-href-or-routerlink-on-an-anchor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *ngIf Else  like this

```
<div *ngIf="isAbsolute; else relative">
  <a [href]="linkUrl" [target]="target" >{{ LinkVal }}</a>
</div>

<ng-template #relative>
  <a [routerLink]="linkUrl" [target]="target">{{ LinkVal }}
</a>
</ng-template>
```