# anchor href vs angular routerlink

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-router

I am trying to use anchor tag with href in my Angular 7 app. When I click on the link the url changes in the browser but the page doesn't get navigated to. It works if I put target="_self" so this works

```
<a href="/abcd" target="_self">Abcd</a>
```

but this does not work only the url changes in the browser but nothing happens

```
<a href="/abcd">Abcd</a>
```

where as if I use Angular routing and use RouterLink it works.

```
<a routerLink="/abcd" routerLinkActive="active">Abcd</a>
```

Can anyone explain the behaviour please.

Comment: see your code before reach ```<a routerLink="/abcd" routerLinkActive="active">Abcd</a>``` you should put ```<router-outlet>```.
From this, we can tell we are using routes.

Comment: Are you sure you are following the syntax correctly....try enclosing with square brackets.... <a [routerLink]="['/abcd']" ></a>
Make sure you specified path in route.ts file correctly.

Comment: if you use `href` it's to call page which is not in your application `routerLink` is the inverse

Comment: I understand that href is a call to a page outside the app but why does it need target="_self". Otherwise the browser URL value changes but the browser doesn't go the url.

Answer (score 50):

**Href** is the basic attribute provided by Html to navigate through pages which **reloads the page on click**.

**routerLink** is the attribute provided by angular to navigate to different components **without reloading the page**.

Major difference between both is that **href kills the state of the current page** where **routerLink doesnt lose the state of the page**.

For Eg. if an input text box is present in the page, the routerLink will retains its value after navigation.The **routerLink  can be considered as the custom attribute of href in angular by overriding some of the features like Page reloading**

Answer (score 7):

**Navigating using href:**

href is the default attribute provided by browsers for navigating (switching) between pages, where the entire page will be get re-loaded losing the current state.

whereas the hack is by preventing the default behavior.

for example:

Inside template:

```
 <a href="route" (click)=onClick($event) />
```

Inside Component:

```
onClick(event :Event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Using the target attribute in href:

```
Please refer to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_target.asp
```

**Navigating using routerLink:**

Angular mimics the above behaviour inside routerLink directive

Answer (score 6):

Angular applications are Single Page Applications (SPA). Using href breaks that design pattern. The effect is that each navigation that utilises href completely resets your application state. Always avoid href when using Angular or any other SPA.

routerLink loads resources internal to Angular, and the page that loaded in the browser is never completely reloaded (and so app state is maintained.) A clue to this being the case is the browser's loading indicator:

When traditional links are followed, you'll see in your browser the spinner going (on the tab, or by the address bar in most cases.) When you're waiting for Angular components to load, that spinner will be idle.

It's something I always check when developing, when my state resets. Sometimes the problem is that I used href instead of routerLink.

Answer (score 5):

Using **href** directly **tells** the browser to open the **link as a new**, such that the app will be **reloaded** and still linked to the exact page that it has been configured for.

Based on the [doc](https://angular.io/guide/router), **routerLink** navigates the app without reloading using the internal api.

you could click the link that uses **href** and **routerLink** to see the difference [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsezw8?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Bonus points for conciseness and a demo link

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you can't use routerLink, if for example, you are in a non angular web component.

A workaround that I used to get around the refresh problem was to check all "a" tag clicks and prevent the default behaviour if a routerlink attribute wasn't present and then use the router to navigate.

```
  @HostListener('window:click', ['$event'])
  onClick(e: any) {
    const path = e.composedPath() as Array<any>;
    const firstAnchor = path.find(p => p.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a');
    if (firstAnchor && !firstAnchor.hasAttribute('routerlink')) {
      const href = firstAnchor.getAttribute('href');

      this.router.navigateByUrl(href);

      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

Comment: My "sometimes you can't use routerLink" scenario was: implementing a pipe that converts marked up text to sanitized HTML. Custom markup processed through the pipe sets certain portions of text as bold, etc. in the rendered HTML.  Where it was failing was having the pipe decorate text as a link - that I wanted to navigate to the next view without a page reload.  Nothing worked.  An answer to another question explained: rendered HTML can't process angular (such as routerLink) - it's too late.  But the above onClick listener by @Lee Gunn provided me a workaround that worked great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Bytech has a correct answer but there is a case when you would want to use href in angular. For instance I have a single application that has multiple projects in it. On a link I want to navigate from the store project to the member portal project. In this case since they are served at two different base urls(in this case for dev environment its localhost:4201 && localhost:4202) using router link will not actually route you to the other base route location. Using href is required or it will fail routing you to the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

Difference:

```
routerLink: 
 - URL changes without page reload -> activates angular router 
 - maintains the page state
       
href: 
- if href is used instead of routerLink - it will work but page will reload 
- href kills the state of the current page
```

Answer (score -1):

If your using href in angular app then avoid it. Angular has router feature where routerLink is part of that.

```
<p routerLink='/path'>Text</p>
```

For more understanding check this article [Angular Routing](https://medium.com/@itsyou/angular-dynamic-routes-with-easy-example-c3fa64fbc768)