# Angular - After Build Inner Routing Not Working - 404 Error

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9, angular-builder

I am using Angular 9.0 and everything is working fine in `ng serve -o` mode but when i try to build the project using `ng build` i can only view the root page. When i try to go to any other page it returns 404 error something i am not experiencing in local `ng serve` mode. Any clues on how to fix the issue?

So http://www.example.com/ << this page opens fine but
http://www.example.com/dashboard returns 404

Edit:
In order to test difference scenarios, to see what might be causing the problem I have managed to identify the issue. Navigation works fine if I use routerLink, but it doesn't work if I use href or window.location.href. Any idea why it would crash when using href or window.location.href ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng serve` automatically takes care of URL redirects to the `index.html`.

The following addition in your `app.module.ts` should solve your problem.

```
import { PathLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

...

providers: [ { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy } ]
```

https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy

Edit:

> href is the default attribute provided by browsers for navigating (switching) between pages, where the entire page will be get re-loaded losing the current state.

[A more detailed explanation on href vs routerLink.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58082769/11972189)

So if you are hosting your files on a Apache server it tries to find a `index.html` file inside the `/dashboard` directory which doesn't exist, thus the 404 error.
To solve this you'll have to rewrite all your traffic back to `index.html`.
[A more detailed explanation on rewrites.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740184/11972189)

Comment: thank you for your response. This providers part also goes into app.module.ts? Wanted to confirm because as per the example on the angular.io it goes on each page in the project.

Comment: Yes that's right. It goes inside the `@NgModule` decorator.

Comment: How are you serving your `index.html` file?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Zan I updated my question and added more info under the heading Edit. Do you think that might help?