# Angular context not matching

Tags: angular, express

My Angular server is not responding to `http://localhost:8449/spreadsheet-upload`, I have a base `href='/spreadsheet-upload"` and routes that begin with that. I would like to begin all references to my server with hostname:port/spreadsheet-upload. I had this in my `index.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%;">

<head>
  <base href="/spreadsheet-upload">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Costing Uploads</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.16/b-1.5.1/b-flash-1.5.1/b-html5-1.5.1/sc-1.4.4/sl-1.2.5/datatables.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>
</head>

<body class="ds-has-sticky-footer">
  <app-root></app-root>
  <footer class="ds-sticky-footer ds-grid ds-bg-neutral-warm-2 ds-z-low ds-affix-bottom ds-text-neutral-warm-8"
    style="width: 100%; height: 50px;">
    <div class="ds-row">
      <div class="ds-offset-xs-1 ds-col-xs-10">
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.10.16/b-1.5.1/b-flash-1.5.1/b-html5-1.5.1/sc-1.4.4/sl-1.2.5/datatables.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My app-routing.module.ts file is now:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: SpreadsheetComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'spreadsheet-upload/', component: SpreadsheetComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'about/', component: AboutComponent, children: [
      { path: 'spreadsheet-upload/about/', component: AboutComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'error/auth', component: ErrorComponent, data: { forbidden: true }, children: [
      { path: 'spreadsheet-upload/error/auth', component: ErrorComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'error/badgateway', component: ErrorComponent, data: { badgatesssway: true }, children: [
      { path: 'spreadsheet-upload/error/badgateway', component: ErrorComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

I tried adding the child paths to get it to start with that context, but it still does not. My console error message is:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'spreadsheet-upload'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'spreadsheet-upload'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1385)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:1365)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:100)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:132)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:106)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:132)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:106)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:132)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:106)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:108)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

Separately, is there a way to pay someone a token of appreciation in say bitcoin for helpful answers?

```
$>ng -version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 6.2.3
Node: 12.13.0
OS: linux x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.8.3
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.3
@schematics/angular          0.8.3
@schematics/update           0.8.3
rxjs                         6.2.2
typescript                   2.9.2
```

Comment: You might also want to use `routerLink` instead of `href`. `href` reloads your page (and loses your state), while `routerLink` doesn't. [More detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081360/anchor-href-vs-angular-routerlink)

Comment: @RubenSzekér Thank you will read your link in more depth. However, most of the details suggested the attribute applied to an anchor element and not the base element

Answer (score 1):

You should be define "spreadsheet-upload" route first. After that, you set up the initial relative URL ('') redirect to "spreadsheet-upload".

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "spreadsheet-upload",
    component: SpreadsheetComponent
  },
  {
    path: "about/",
    component: AboutComponent
  },
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/spreadsheet-upload",
    pathMatch: "full"
  }
];
```