# conditionally use either click or href in anchor tag in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Hi i want to use either href or (click) based on condition in anchor tab.

I tried `*ngIf="link.linkName==Grills Data?(click)={{ link.url }}: href={{ link.url }}"` but it throws error.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44449222/4658957

Comment: Use ngIfElse as @bastien suggested

Comment: I tried but its not working

Comment: What error you're facing when using ifElse?

Answer (score 0):

you can call function and check your condition into your function like this

In component.html

```
<a (click)="onClick(link)"></a>
```

in component.ts

```
onClick(link) {
   if(link.linkName == 'Grills Data') {
      // do something
   } else {
       // the line bellow will navigate to the link.url
       window.location.href = link.url
   }
}
```